# Automapper Map Interface With 2 Concrete Classes to Another Class

Tags: c#, automapper

Suppose I have the following

```
public interface IPerson {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Student : IPerson{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string StudentId {get;set;}
}

public class Professor : IPerson {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string ProfessorId {get;set;}
}

public class PersonDto {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string StudentId {get;set;}
    public string ProfessorId {get;set;}
}
```

But now when I create the maps

```
class MyMapperProfile : Profile{
    CreateMap<Student, PersonDto>()
        .ForMember(s => s.ProfessorId, s=> s.Ignore());
    CreateMap<Student, PersonDto>()
        .ForMember(s => s.StudentId, s=> s.Ignore());

    CreateMap<IPerson, PersonDto>()
        .Include<Student, PersonDto>()
        .Include<Professor, PersonDto>();
}
```

I notice that the map does not work (does not map). In fact, I get errors when I validate the map (StudentId is not mapped, etc.)

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Can you show the maps for student and professor?

Comment: @Cal279 Updated the code.

Comment: Is that a copy error or are you defining `Student` to `PersonDto` twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below mapping configuration should work. Note that you did not create a mapping for professor in your example (could be a copy-paste error).

```
        CreateMap<Student, PersonDto>()
            .ForMember(s => s.StudentId, o => o.MapFrom(x => x.StudentId))
            .ForMember(s => s.ProfessorId, o => o.Ignore());

        CreateMap<Professor, PersonDto>()
            .ForMember(s => s.ProfessorId, o => o.MapFrom(x => x.ProfessorId))
            .ForMember(s => s.StudentId, o => o.Ignore());

        CreateMap<IPerson, PersonDto>()
            .ForMember(s => s.StudentId, o => o.Ignore())
            .ForMember(s => s.ProfessorId, o => o.Ignore())
            .Include<Student, PersonDto>()
            .Include<Professor, PersonDto>();
```

Also note that I am explicitly setting the fields here. See [Specifying inheritance in derived classes](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Mapping-inheritance), in particular the below section:

> **Inheritance Mapping Priorities**
>
> This introduces additional complexity because there are multiple ways a property can be mapped. The priority of these sources are as follows
>
> - Explicit Mapping (using .MapFrom())
> - Inherited Explicit Mapping
> - Ignore Property Mapping
> - Convention Mapping (Properties that are matched via convention)

Although, to be honest, this may not be what you want.